# Finding the process which sent signal in c

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a child process which might receive sigterm signal from its parent or from somewhere else. I have to take appropriate action if the signal is from parent. 
How can i find if the received signal is from parent in c(linux)?

Comment: Actually, I just realized you were asking about SIGKILL.  There is no way to do what you want.  If the child is sent a SIGKILL it is dead, end of story.

Comment: SIGKILL can't be caught.The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately (kill). In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

Comment: sorry it is sigterm. i edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up your signal handler with `sigaction` using the `SA_SIGINFO` flag.  Your handler will accept a parameter of `siginfo_t`.  Within the siginfo_t struct is the field `si_pid`.  This is the process id of the sending process.  Match that against the child's `ppid().`

Comment: thanks.We have used signal() to capture the signal. is there anyway to find the process without using sigaction?

Comment: Sure, you can use alternatives like `sigwaitinfo`, `sigtimedwait`, etc. if this fits what you are doing.  But as far as I am aware getting the pid out of a siginfo_t struct is the only way.  Also since this is linux there is also `signalfd` which will (similarly) capture the sending pid in the `signalfd_siginfo.ssi_uid` field.